# not opening chrome browser after updating Chrome browser to latest version

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

After I've updated google chrome browser to the latest version when I trying to run the browser tab crashing.

Error:

```
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: session not created exception
from disconnected: unable to send message to renderer
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.139)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Tried to downrage to chrome `v65` and chrome webdriver `v2.36`

```html
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: session not created exception
from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540470 (e522d04694c7ebea4ba8821272dbef4f9b818c91),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Comment: Update the question with your code trial and error stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Support version  `Chrome v63-65` use  `ChromeDriver v2.36`
You can refer below link :- http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.36/notes.txt

Comment: Tried to downrage but still same error: question updated