# Chrome web driver crashing after updating Chrome browser to latest version

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

After I've updated google chrome browser to the latest version when I trying to run the browser tab crashing.

Error:

```
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: session not created exception
from disconnected: unable to send message to renderer
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.139)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [not opening chrome browser after updating Chrome browser to latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50114703/not-opening-chrome-browser-after-updating-chrome-browser-to-latest-version)

Comment: Downgrade versions of Driver. I think v.33 working perfect

Comment: @Zhivko.Kostadinov Same error

Comment: @JangoPay Ok, take  a look here (we try to solve the same problem) :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50113359/python-selenium-not-running-with-chrome-driver-chrome-version?noredirect=1#comment87281289_50113359

Comment: Duplicated with 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50113359/python-selenium-not-running-with-chrome-driver-chrome-version

Comment: some debugging steps here https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/chrome-doesn-t-start